# Problemas com o number_format(PHP) por dois pontos no numeral

Tags: php

Estou tendo problemas com a função `number_format` do PHP, pois o meu numeral vem do banco de dados com dois pontos, ex:

> 1.235.32

Estou usando o `number_format` dessa forma:

```
number_format(floatval('1.235.32'), 2, ',', '.');
```

E ele me resulta isso:

> 1.22

Preciso que meu resultado fique formatado assim:

> 1235,32

Comment: Eita, vem com dois pontos? como está no seu banco o tipo de dado?

Comment: a formatação deve ser algum padrão, esse formato 1.235.32 não é um formato válido, se não tiver como arrumar o input no banco, você vai ter q fazer um replace no pontos para funcionar a formatação.

Comment: @Virgilio.Novic , Eduardo Realmente, eu estava formatando errado antes de mandar para o banco de dados. Acham que devo apagar a pergunta?

Comment: @TalesBreno talvez seja melhor postar agora uma resposta sua dizendo aonde estava errando e como solucionou o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso não seja possível mudar o input dos dados, use essa solução:

```
// Elimina a pontuação
$value = str_replace('.', '', '100.235.32');

// Adiciona a pontuação correta
$value = substr_replace($value, '.', strlen($value) - 2, 0);

echo number_format($value, 2, ',', '.');
```

[substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-replace.php) - Substitui o texto dentro de uma parte de uma string

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte, seria isso?:

```
 substr(str_replace('.','','1.235.32'),0,strlen(str_replace('.','','1.235.32'))-2).".".substr('1.235.32',-2);
```

Meio gabiarra mas acho que é isso...
Espero ter ajudado!!